# PHP zend_call_method with arguments passed by reference

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am currently rewriting our PHP extension from PHP5 to PHP7. To call PHP methods from our C/C++ code we use slightly modified `zend_call_method` from Zend/zend_interfaces.c (to use more arguments than 2). Now I found out that it does not work with arguments passed by reference,

`public function FuncWithRef(array &$changeThis)`

if they are changed in the PHP code then zval values in C part are not influenced. In PHP5 the value was overwritten as expected and could be used later in C code.

Previously the `zend_fcall_info` struct for function call was filled with params simply by

`params[0] = &arg1;`

In PHP7 this is changed to

`ZVAL_COPY_VALUE(&params[0], arg1);`

After function is executed (`zend_call_function`) both `fci.params` and `arg1` contain still the original zval values, changes made in PHP code are not available. I tried things like using DUP instead of COPY but with no result. Is there any way how to solve this? I am mainly searching for and comparing code snippets in PHP/ext folder to see how things were rewritten from PHP5 to PHP7 and this seems to be hopefully the last part missing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two differences between PHP5 and PHP7 approach in zend_call_method:

```
fci.no_separation = 0;
```

has to be set. Then fci.params are changed inside zend_call_function and then they have to be manually copied back to zend_call_method input args.